# my ff app not working in test mode but its working fine preview mode, not any widget or any functionality

Tags: flutterflow

my ff app not workign in test mode but its working fine preview mode.it was working fine yesterday. in test mode only app bar nd nav bar is showing without any widget or any functionality[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkLhF.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAlPo.png). its happening after i havee started using FF windowns app

tried cache clearing.But not worked